# qmake rules for generated code

Tags: qt, qmake

I realized my earlier question was a little confused about the rules and dependencies. The following .pro file generates a makefile which works correctly IF the source files in the directory 'generated' exist at the time qmake runs.

```
idl.target   = generated/qmtest.h
idl.commands = code_generator 
idl.config   = no_link
idl.depends  = $$SOURCES $$HEADERS $$FORMS

TEMPLATE       = app
INCLUDEPATH    += generated
SOURCES        += generated/*.cpp
PRE_TARGETDEPS += generated/qmtest.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_UNIX_TARGETS += idl
```

But when qmake runs, its only generating a makefile, and PRE_TARGETDEPS & QMAKE_EXTRA_UNIX_TARGETS don't help me. How can I get qmake to generate a makefile which will add the contents of generated/ to SOURCES?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to do this in two passes.

In your qmake file, add the following line:

```
include( generated/generated.pri )
```

Then, at the end of your code_generator script, add the sources to the generated.pri file (using bash for the example, but the idea is the same for almost all languages):

```
rm generated/generated.pri
for file in $( ls generated/*.cpp ); do
    echo "SOURCES += ${file}" >> generated/generated.pri
done
```

The first time you run the qmake file, generated/generated.pri will presumably be empty.   When you run make, it will populate the generated.pri file.  The second time, it will recreate the make file (as a source .pri file changed), then compile again.  You might be able to fiddle around with other commands which would do the second stage for you.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up forcing the generator to run during qmake using system($$idl.commands). The makefile it generates is correct and since I added the output to the target it doesn't really hurt anything.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue just now, but for a simpler usecase of just a single generated file. For that, I found a much simpler way to achieve this by using GENERATED_SOURCES instead of SOURCES:

```
dummyfile.target = dummy.cpp
dummyfile.commands = touch $$dummyfile.target
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += dummyfile
GENERATED_SOURCES += $$dummyfile.target
```

Probably one could push that into a qmake loop and generate the proper targets for multiple files as well.

Comment: + PRE_TARGET_DEPENDS += dummyfile

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution that I believe to be robust and general, that relies on `qmake` generating a GNU Makefile.

Say we've got all extra `SOURCES` and `HEADERS` assignments in a file named `Makefile.pri`, which gets generated by executing the script `generate_Makefile.pri.sh` that also generates the sources and/or headers mentioned in `Makefile.pri`.

We want this file automatically and reliably generated by the build system itself, so to be included in the `.pro` file, so that `qmake` can take into account its content and generate the Makefile with the proper dependencies.

This is then what we have to put in our `.pro` file.

```
Makefile_pri.target   = Makefile.pri
Makefile_pri.commands = generate_Makefile.pri.sh
Makefile_pri.depends  = FORCE

Makefile.target  = $$MAKEFILE
Makefile.depends = Makefile_pri

include($$Makefile_pri.target)

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS = Makefile Makefile_pri
```

This way:

1. if there's no `Makefile.pri`, then it gets created;
2. If `Makefile.pri` gets created or updated, then `qmake` runs again and takes into account its content, regenerating the `Makefile`

As said, this **does** depend on `qmake` generating a GNU Makefile, but the same approach I believe could be adapted to work also with other target build systems.